# node mssql throws error: pool is draining and cannot accept work

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I have a node js app with the npm mssql module. I have purchased a cloud Windows 2012 server and when trying to call the stored procedure, it throws the error.

Throws error at **ps.prepare("exec usp_Get_Cars @param", function(err)**

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var util = require('util');
var recieve = require('./recieve');
var userID = "7DF506E1-700D-4D30-8162-74A903743561";

app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.use('/style', express.static(__dirname + '/style'));
app.use('/script', express.static(__dirname + '/script'));

var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
  user: 'prod_admin',
  password: 'myPassword',
  server: 'serverName',
  database: 'elements'
};

app.get("/getCars/:userID", function(req, res) {
  var userID = req.params.userID;
  var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
    var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(connection);
    ps.input('param', sql.NVarChar(sql.MAX));
    ps.prepare("exec usp_Get_Cars @param", function(err) {
      ps.execute({
        param: userID
      }, function(err, recordset) {
        console.log('Recordset: ' + JSON.stringify(recordset));
        res.send(recordset);
        ps.unprepare(function(err) {
          console.log('Error on unprepare: ' + err);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('home.html', {
    'root': __dirname + '/templates'
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Node server running @ http://localhost:3000');
});
```

I did try searching for why this error occurs, but can't find anything relating to mssql or node. You can see the code that [throws the error here](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool/blob/b89166bd10eb3e28f7499c394cde8cace8b9fbb6/lib/generic-pool.js#L384-L386). I am wondering if this is an issue with the server setup?

There are no errors in the js file and I have no issues running this on my Windows 10 local machine. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you close your connections? If you don't close them, I suspect they will stay open and eventually time out. Depending on how fast you request, you may run out of connections, because they are kept open in the pool

Comment: @Psi It seems like the error occurs before the connection is made. I have added connection.close() at the end, but that didn't do anything. And according to the [docs here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#prepared-statement), it says that calling ps.unprepare() should release the connection back to the pool.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a firewall issue with AWS. I was unable to determine how to fix it through Amazon. But I moved my database to another server and it worked.